# Status item pop up menu deprecated in OS X 10.14

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

The only way I can get the status item to display the menu when right clicked is by called the popUpMenu()

```
@objc func statusBarPressed(button: NSButton){
    let event = NSApp.currentEvent
    let bundleId =  button.layer?.value(forKey: Constants.NSUserDefaultsKeys.bundleId) as! String
    let item = MyObj.statusItems.filter{$0.button == button}.first
    if event?.type == NSEvent.EventType.rightMouseUp {
        print("Right click")
        item?.popUpMenu(MyObj.menu) //works but depr
    } else {
        print("Left click")
    }
}
```

Is there any way to use non deprecated methods to achieve this? Using

```
button.menu =  MyObj.menu
button.menu?.popUp(positioning: nil, at: NSPoint(x: 0, y: button.frame.height), in: button)
```

gives a similar result, but the pop up menu is floating and not a drop down of the menu bar item like I want it.

Comment: Any difference with "+ (void)popUpContextMenu:(NSMenu*)menu withEvent:(NSEvent*)event forView:(NSView*)view;" ?

Comment: Make sure your NSStatusItem has a valid NSStatusBarButton and after you can set menu to your NSStatusItem. Once you have button in statusBarPressed call performClick method (internally it calls the deprecated method but that's not your issue)

Comment: popUpContextMenu doesn't seem to be an available method, and i want it to be a right click.performClick just recursively calls the buttonClicked func I implemented and doesn't actually show the menu

Comment: look at internal implementation if you don't believe me what is apple doing. Hopper (free) + AppKit.framework. You will see what they do and what you missed.

Comment: popUpContextMenu is a class method and is always available. I am using objective-c naming so look it up

Comment: popUpContextMenu just keeps the floating menu, same problem as before. How do I look at the internal implementation? I can only seem to view the headers/declarations

Comment: Hopper + dissambly AppKit.framework. Use google/youtube

Comment: what's google??

Comment: How do I look internal implementation? The answer is use app called hopper and dissasembly appkit framework. Display pseudocode of function you need [NSStatusItem popUpMenu]. If you don't know how it works use google to search for hopper tutorials. http://hopperapp.com/   https://imgur.com/a/Bnt62yP The image shows that perform click utilizes the same popup function if your menu is correctly setup. PS: Mac users are not used to right click on nsstatusbar. PS2: use lldb command "br set -n popUpStatusItemMenu:" as a breakpoint to see that it will go there.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0q7GYTL